# Novice Coder with issue properly looping

Tags: python-3.x, loops

So I'm a novice coder having never coded before and am teaching myself Python on the guidance of my CS instructor. I'm walking myself through "Automating the Boring Stuff with Python" and I'm having issues with the Collatz sequence portion at the end of Chapter 3. I've got the sequence down but I'm having issues properly looping the code in order to get the result I want which is looping the sequence until the answer is == to integer 1. This is what I have and I would love some feedback and assistance.

```
def collatz(number): #defines the collatz sequence
    if number%2 == 0:
        num1 = number//2
    else:
        num1 = 3 * (number + 1)
    return num1

print("Let's try the collatz sequence. Enter a number")
num = int(input())
num3 = collatz(num)
while num3 != 1: #loops collatz sequence until it equals 1
    num2 = collatz(num3)
    if num2 == 1:
        break
    else:
        num3 = collatz(num2)    
print("ta da!")
```

Comment: What happened when you ran this? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need this code:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        num1 = number//2
    else: num1 = 3 * number + 1 # Do not use brackets!!! Or you will have infinite loop
    return num1

print("Let's try the collatz sequence. Enter a number")
num = int(input())
while num != 1:
    num = collatz(num)
    print(num)
    if num == 1: break
print("ta da!"); input()
```

Comment: Okay thank you for that. It looks like I was close. Excuse my ignorance but why would brackets create an infinite loop?

Comment: For example, collatz with brackets will convert 1 to 6, 6 to 3, 3 to 12, 12 to 6, 6 to 3, and again... Infinite!

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense to me now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatthewCardiel You are welcome. Please accept my answer if it was really useful to you.